# Create animation from 2 or more spritesheets - Phaser

Tags: javascript, animation, phaser-framework

Say I have a sequence of 100 png images (523x482 each frame).

I'm thinking on creating groups of 9 images in a spritesheet or atlas.
But is it possible to create an animation from separate spritesheets/atlas?

```
// frame00 and frame01 are spritesheets with 9 frames.
const anim = this.game.add.sprite(265, 70, 'frame_00', 0, scene);
anim.animations.add('anim', ['frame_01']); // it does not work
anim.animations.play('anim', 30, true);
```

Got the following error:

```
phaser.min.js:3 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'index' of undefined
at i.Animation.updateCurrentFrame (phaser.min.js:3)
at i.Animation.play (phaser.min.js:3)
at i.AnimationManager.play (phaser.min.js:3)
```

How can I create an animation from this sequence or what would be the best approach to follow?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid this isn't possible in Phaser 2 due to the way the animation system works. It's something I changed to be possible in Phaser 3, but looking at your code you're using v2.

Comment: Yes I am using Phaser 2 :(